# How to initialize IBaseFilter struct in Rust?

Tags: windows, rust

```rust
unsafe {
    match CoInitialize(None) {
        Ok(result) => {}
        Err(error) => {
            eprintln!("error: {:?}", error);
            return Err(error);
        }
    }

    let graph: IGraphBuilder =
        CoCreateInstance(&CLSID_FilterGraph, None, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER)?;

    let _device_filter: Option<IBaseFilter> = None;
    match graph.AddFilter(_device_filter.as_ref().unwrap(), None) {
        Ok(ok) => {
            println!("add filter ok");
        }
        Err(error) => {
            eprintln!("error: {:?}", error);
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried all the methods I know and consulted the documentation.

I couldn't find the interface to create IBaseFilter. Please help me solve this problem. Thank you very much.

This is similar C++ code, and it can work properly.

```cpp
IGraphBuilder* graph;
IBaseFilter*   device_filter;
hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FilterGraph, nullptr, CLSCTX_INPROC, IID_IGraphBuilder, (void**)&graph);

if (FAILED(hr)) {
    return hr;
}

hr = graph->AddFilter(device_filter, nullptr);
if (FAILED(hr)) {
    printf("CoCreateInstance CLSID_FilterGraph failed.\n");
    return hr;
}
// ...
```

Comment: Your `match CoInitialize` block can be replaced with a more idiomatic `if let Err(error) = CoInitialize(None) { ... }` or even just by `CoInitialize(None)?;` which will return the error (but not print anything). Also, if you are getting any errors, it would be good to include those.

Comment: CoCreateInstance didn't throw any errors. My current issue is that I want to use the AddFilter function of IGraphBuilder to obtain _device_filter, but I haven't found how IBaseFilter is initialized. Passing Option<IBaseFilter> as an argument results in an invalid pointer.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directshow/add-a-filter-by-clsid

Comment: In the rs package for Windows 0.52.0, there is no AddFilterByCLSID function, so I have been curious about how to create IBaseFilter.

Comment: Read the last paragraph of the link. You either CoCreateInstance it or enumerate it.